# Select with IF statement on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, case, aggregate-functions

I have a code like that:

```
select
    tbl.person
    ,COUNT(distinct tbl.project)
    ,if (tbl.stage like '%SIGNED%') then sum(tbl.value) else '0' end if as test
from
    my_table tbl
group by
1
```

And it returns me that error message:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "then"
```

I didn't got it. As I saw on documentation, the if statement syntax appears to be used correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Postgres, I would recommend using `filter`:

```
select tbl.person, COUNT(distinct tbl.project)
       sum(tbl.value) filter (where tbl.stage like '%SIGNED%') as test
from my_table tbl
group by 1;
```

`if` is control flow logic.  When working with queries, you want to learn how to think more as sets.  So the idea is to filter the rows and add up the values after filtering.

Comment: Nice! I also think that will give me better results instead of using `if`. Hadn't thought of doing this way

Answer (score 15):

`IF` is to be used in procedures, not in queries. Use a `case` expression instead:

```
select
    tbl.person
    ,COUNT(distinct tbl.project)
    ,sum(case when tbl.stage like '%SIGNED%' then tbl.value else 0 end) as test
from
    my_table tbl
group by
1
```

Notes:

- `tbl.stage` is not part of the `group by`, so it should most probably be enclosed within the aggregate expression, not outside of it
- all values returned by a `case` expression need to have the same datatype. Since `sum(tbl.value)` is numeric, the `else` branch should return `0` (number), not `'0'` (string).

Comment: Thank you, it works fine!
Do you know why does the if statement causes that error? Because in the postgresql documentation I've found exactly this piece of code as an example:
`IF a = b THEN
   select * from eq_prod;
ELSE
   select * from fn_pes;
END IF;
`

Comment: @GuilhermeStorti: `IF` is a statement, that is meant to be used in control structures, ie in PL/pgSQL code (functions, procedures...). This is [explained in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html).

Comment: It is a matter of what structures can be nested in other structures. The structure "IF _expression_ then Select ..." nests the SQL within the If structure. A perfactlly nesting.  However the structure "Select ... if ..." nests the IF within the SQL. A totally different construct. Once an SQL statement is initiated only SQL constructs can be used until the statement comes the an end. And there is no "IF" in SQL..

Comment: Postgresql should consider improve usability as easy as T-SQL so users can focus on what they want to achieve vs. how to fit in.

Answer (score 4):

replace

```
if (tbl.stage like '%SIGNED%') then sum(tbl.value) else '0' end if as test
```

with

```
sum(case when tbl.stage like '%SIGNED%' then tbl.value end) as test
```

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen two answers posted within the same second!

Comment: Thank you, it works fine!
Do you know why does the if statement causes that error? Because in the postgresql documentation I've found exactly this piece of code as an example:
`IF a = b THEN
   select * from eq_prod;
ELSE
   select * from fn_pes;
END IF;
`

Comment: @GuilhermeStorti: Because that `if` is a flow control statement and is executing 2 different queries and is not within the query.